# Determine relative URL from base URL and full absolute URL

Tags: javascript

I'd like to take the following URLs:

- Base: `https://example.com/this/is/base/resource`
- Absolute: `https://example.com/this/is/up-one/other-resource?possibly-with=querystring`

From there, I'd like to calculate the shortest relative URL from base.  For this example, I should get:

```
../up-one/some-other-resource?possibly-with=querystring
```

Is there a standard method for doing this?  I know there are a lot of edge cases, so before I build it, I wanted to see if a good method already existed.

I know the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) can go the other way around, which is ultimately what I will be using to go back again.

Comment: Can you offer a little back-story on _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: @Phil I have a bunch (hundreds of thousands) of signed URLs for resources in an S3 bucket.  The AWS JS SDK that generates these signed URLs necessarily creates full absolute URLs.  But, since I have so many and they're all relative to a main index file (which will contain the URLs), I figured I could save 50% of the index size by making relative paths.  So, that's why I have to start with two absolute URLs.

Comment: Gzipping your responses will save a lot more bytes. And if you're already gzipping your response, then making a change like this will likely have a negligible impact

Comment: @Phil Yes, I already compress these index files, and the impact of using relative paths is far larger than negligible in my case.  But, thanks for your input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359050/how-to-convert-absolute-url-to-relative