# Getting a relative URL between two absolute URLs

Tags: javascript, url, routes, navigation

Given two absolute URLs:

```js
const from = new URL("https://example.com")
const to = new URL("https://example.com/about")
```

is there an easy and reliable way to get a relative url between them?
(`about` in this case)

It would need to handle:

- Differing origins
- Non-child pages (eg `https://example.com/some-page` to `https://example.com/some-other-page`)
- Query parameters & fragments

Ideally any approach would return the shortest url that navigates from URL a to URL b when used as an `href` attribute on an Anchor.

Comment: What does "between" mean to you here? I don't understand.

Comment: maybe better if u can give exmaples for each case u have mentioned

Comment: What I'm confused about is why _path_ doesn't cover what you're after. Why is the other URL relevant?

Comment: `/about` isn't the shortest relative URL for your example URLs, `about` is the shortest.

Comment: [How to convert absolute url to relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359050/how-to-convert-absolute-url-to-relative)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing [this function](https://gist.github.com/LorisSigrist/55ffe576202e348d804d57d5489e6f5d) that does what I wanted.